# DAX Cumulative VAMI Return

Tags: ssas, dax

Here's a simplified version of my model:

I have P/L (profit and loss) data at the daily level for several funds and several securities. To calculate the % return is easy - it's the P/L divided by the opening AUM (assets under management). But each month the AUM changes significantly due to investor contributions. So, to get a YTD return %, I need to calculate cumulative returns, for which the formula is (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return)):

```
YtdReturn =
PRODUCTX ( MonthlyReturnTable, DIVIDE ( MonthlyReturn, OpeningAUM ) +1 ) -1
```

The difficulty is that my P/L is at the daily level. I successfully created this:

```
    CompoundReturn:=
    PRODUCTX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( tblDates[MonthYearNumber] ),
            "PnL Total1", CALCULATE ( SUM ( PnL[TradingPnL] ) + SUM ( PnL[InterestDividendsPnL] ) ),
            "Month_Opening_AUM1", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Daily_AUM[MonthOpeningAUM] ) )
        ),
        DIVIDE ( [PnL Total1], [Month_Opening_AUM1] ) + 1
    )
        - 1
```

This works well:

[image: ytd returns]

However, I want to do this on a running YTD basis. I'm having trouble setting the "inner" table to YTD. I tried surrounding the `VALUES()` with a `CALCULATETABLE()` to filter by YTD, but didn't work:

```
    CompoundReturn :=
    PRODUCTX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                VALUES ( tblDates[MonthYearNumber] ),
                DATESYTD ( tblDates[Date] )
            ),
            "PnL Total1", CALCULATE ( SUM ( PnL[TradingPnL] ) + SUM ( PnL[InterestDividendsPnL] ) ),
            "Month_Opening_AUM1", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Daily_AUM[MonthOpeningAUM] ) )
        ),
        DIVIDE ( [PnL Total1], [Month_Opening_AUM1] ) + 1
    )
        - 1
```

The result in Excel is not a running return, but individual:

[image: running compound returns]

Any ideas? Thanks!

*Note:* All code formatted with [daxformatter.com](http://www.daxformatter.com/)

Comment: Try `TOTALYTD` Formula. more explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634400.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a friend. I needed to put the `CALCULATETABLE` outside the `ADDCOLUMNS`:

```
CompoundReturn :=
PRODUCTX (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( tblDates[MonthYearNumber] ),
            "PnL Total1", CALCULATE ( SUM ( PnL[TradingPnL] ) + SUM ( PnL[InterestDividendsPnL] ) ),
            "Month_Opening_AUM1", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Daily_AUM[MonthOpeningAUM] ) )
        ),
        DATESYTD ( tblDates[Date] )
    ),
    DIVIDE ( [PnL Total1], [Month_Opening_AUM1] ) + 1
)
    - 1
```